# HTML form field border style

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap v3.1.1 on a HTML form (code below).  Previously, the form border was fine - however, when I added the span for icons inside the form fields, the border no longer appears distinctly visible.  Is there something besides using a border style on the form fields that I can/should use?  Thanks in advance.

```
<form id="login" method="POST" action="/xyz/login" role="form" novalidate>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">&nbsp;Email Address</label>
        <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>   
           <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="on" required data-required-msg="Username is required" 
           autofocus tabindex="1" class="form-control">
        </div>  
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">&nbsp;Password</label>
        <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>  
           <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" class="form-control" 
           required data-required-msg="Password is required" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
  <br>

  <div class="form-group">
       <button id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: when I tried this in jdfiddle, I could see the borders fine but they do not appear to render properly on my browsers (chrome/firefox/IE)

Comment: Please post your changes to the bootstrap stylesheet.

Comment: thanks - I had a rule which was causing the outline and borner to be none.  I removed it and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pilot error - I had the following rule in my stylesheet which was causing the problem.  Removing this rule solved the issue for me.

```
input[type=text]{
   -webkit-appearance:none;
   outline:none;
   border:none;
}
```